# Recommendation system and baseline predictors

Tags: algorithms, predictor, linear-algebra, rms

I'm participating in programming contest, where I have a data, and where the first number is a user, second number is a movie, and the third is a number in then-points rating.

```
0 0 9
0 1 8
1 1 4
1 2 6
2 2 7
```

This data in a table: Rows is users 0, 1 and 2; columns is movies 0, 1 and 2; cells are scores, "-" were not voted on:

[image]

And I have to predict third number for next data:

```
0 2
1 0
2 0
2 1
```

I use this way for finding bias values https://youtube.com/watch?v=dGM4bNQcVKI and this way for predicting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RSigTais8o.

Raw average is `6.8`, because all numbers in table divide to numbers length: (9 + 8 + 4 + 6 + 7) / 5 = 34/5 = 6.8

Bias value for user number 0: `9 + 8 / 2 = 8.5 - 6.8 = 1.7`.

[image]

Bias value for movie number 2: `6 + 7 / 2 = 6.5 - 6.8 = 0.3`.

[image]

And baseline predictors:

[image: https://intern.contest.yandex.ru/testsys/tex/render/XGhhdCByX3t1bX0gPSBcbXUgKyBiX3UgKyBiX20s.png]

`6.8 + 1.7 + 0.3`, where result is `8.8`, but in contest result is: `7.052009`.

And result for all given numbers must be (where the first number is a user, second number is a movie, and the third is a number in then-points rating):

```
0 2 7.052009
1 0 6.687943
2 0 6.995272
2 1 6.687943
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you explain / describe your methods in addition to providing links to youtube videos? Few people may want to watch the videos to understand & be able to answer your question.

Comment: @gung I updated my question.